# Showing the relationship between Lucas and Fibonacci numbers with a recursive relationship

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the equation

$$L_{n+k}-(-1)^kL_{n-k}=5F_kF_n$$

Where $\{L\}$ is the set of Lucas numbers and $\{F\}$ is a Fibonacci sequence, $n$ and $k$ are both $>0$ and integers, how would one develop this into a recursive relationship? Would a different approach be needed instead of just trying to rearrange my existing formula?

Comment: Oh yes.. thanks for that, a lot simpler

Comment: Is that formula actually right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers

Comment: say n=10 and k=3,  

    L(13)-(-1)^3*L(7)=5F(3)F(10),  
    521+29=5*2*55,  
    550=550,  
Yeah :)